# can we separate out absolute value function like this?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$
> \lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x(x-2)}{|(x+1)(x-2)|}=
> \lim_{x\to 2^-}\left(\frac{x}{|x+1|}\cdot \frac{x-2}{|x-2|}\right)
> $$

So as the title says, is it okay to separate function under absolute value  like this (i.e In form of Products) as shown in the denominator?

Comment: Note that for $C,D\neq 0$, $$\frac{AB}{|CD|}=\frac{AB}{|C|\cdot|D|}=\frac{A}{|C|}\cdot\frac{B}{|D|}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $|ab|=|a||b|$ holds for all $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general $|ab|=|a||b|$.  You can check all the sign combinations to justify it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course we can di that since the two expressions are equivalent, moreover in that case we can also go beyond that indeed

$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{x(x-2)}{|(x+1)(x-2)|}=
\lim_{x\to 2^-}\left(\frac{x}{|x+1|}\cdot \frac{x-2}{|x-2|}\right)=\lim_{x\to 2^-}\left(\frac{x}{|x+1|}\right)\cdot \lim_{x\to 2^-}\left(\frac{x-2}{|x-2|}\right)$$

since the two limits exist and are finite.